# Build json object dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have some date which will come dynamically and it will be in the following form:

```
April Bug Fix Study/A-000000027/Operational Procedure Manual/1572.pdf

April Bug Fix Study/Asia/April Bug Fix Site/Operational Procedure Manual/Drug Export Form.pdf

April Bug Fix Study/Asia/April Bug Fix Site/Subject 1/Insurance/Burp_Suit.docx

April Bug Fix Study/Asia/April Bug Fix Site/Subject 1/Trial Management Plan/GrantRequest.txt
```

Now I have to display this data in tree strucuture.

I am very new to implement this type of functionality .Could any please help me out how to display this data in Html tree sturcture.

Thanks in Advance.

Shaik.

Comment: Are you wanting to display the contents of the pdf files and the txt files or simply have links to those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i 'm not sure of how your data structure is but as per your data and display format you can try this

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
var marleft = 0;
var inarr = arr[i].split("/");
for(var j=1;j<inarr.length;j++){
    html += "<div style='margin-left:" + marleft + "px;'>" + inarr[j] + "</div>";
    marleft += 15;
}
$("#content").html(html);
```

}

The working fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/ST8dE/1/)

Comment: Hi Vinod,Thanks for quick reply.I saw the output in the fiddle,it seems almost done.But we have to loop through every key which i listed above .So April Bug Fix Study will be the root element.When looping through every key we will have to chek whether the subchild element exists in the above key,if exists we have to insert in that category instead of creating another child elements.Please let me know if u need more info.

Comment: ya rest can be manipulated as we want .. mark answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Actually i have to display the tree structure some thing like from this site:http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/ .is it possible?

Comment: yes it can just instead of div use table markup and then let the above plugin take hold of it

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code of this type if possible.Thanks.

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/3XkTD/ now just try to set the table markup as in the answer its done using div

Comment: Thank you so much vinod.My last question is can we show the data(which i posted above) in this format(which you created) dynamically? I mean on the page load  we need to loop through all keys and show it in the tree form like how you show it in the fiddle.Thanks.

Comment: yes its possible build the mark up as you want

Comment: Could you please help me out to provid the markup for my requirement.